# Cannot import custom typescript package in node.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-modules

So after a few hours of banging my head against the wall, I decided to ask stackoverflow.
I have a custom typescript project/package which I would like to use with [zx](https://github.com/google/zx). I used `npm pack` and installed the tar.gz globally, when I try to `require` or `import` my custom module I always get the error `ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND` and I can't seem to find the right typescript configuration to make this work. What has to be done to make a typescript module importable in a normal node.js script? This is my current `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [ "es2015" ],
    "target": "es5",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "strict": true,
    "types": ["node", "jest"]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

if this is to little information, here is the link to the repo https://github.com/mak1A4/sn-request

EDIT: I already have the `NODE_PATH` environment variable set in my `.zshrc` and also tried installing the tar.gz locally inside a normal node.js project, with the same result :-/

Answer (score 0):

I changed my config based on this repo [example-typescript-package](https://github.com/tomchen/example-typescript-package) didn't work either ... but after fixing the typo I made in the import statement it worked ^^